Name for a disjoint union of primitive group actions
Let $G$ be a finite group and $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ the set of all primitive $G$-sets up to isomorphism, i.e. it contains a copy of each isomorphism class of primitive $G$-sets.
Then, $\coprod_{i\in I} X_i$, the disjoint union of all primitive $G$-sets, is itself a $G$-set by the simultaneous action. Does this $G$-set has a name?
It is in general not primitive as it is not transitive. It has the property that all $G$-sets without a fixed point have a $G$-morphism into it and it is the smallest set with this property.
